# Pyperclip module installed but not found when program runs from cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, python-module

I wrote a program that use pyperclip module and it would work from Pycharm and python IDLE, would work as well if starting from Powershell but if I try to start the program from WIN+R, when launched, the program returns an error saying that pyperclip module is not installed. The same problem appears when I run it from the Anaconda Powershell Prompt.

PLEASE NOTICE: 
The program was working perfectly before I installed Anaconda and Jupyterlab.
The error occurs when I run the program from the cmd using WIN+R AND when I run it from the Anaconda Command Prompt but it's fine when run from IDLE, Powershell, Pycharm.
I always used python 3 and only yesterday I installed Anaconda.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: if you have two Pythons then you may have `pyperclip` installed in one Python and code uses other Python to run it . Install `pyperclip` in all Pythons.

Comment: Hi, I thought about it but then is there a way to know which one is running which? And when I run the cmd from WIN+R which Python would run between the two? Is it related with the path? Thanks

Comment: you could run script with `import sys` `print(sys.version)` `print(sys.executable)` `print(sys.path)` to see which version is used by `WIN+R` and other tools.

Comment: Tried and everything seems fine: the executable is not the one coming with Anaconda. In fact I run python from every platform and Anaconda show up only when I run python from the Anaconda prompt but any other time python always run from the first exe installed, the one in the usual path C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32. If is taken from there, pyperclip is installed already and is fully working because if I run it any other way I don't have any problem. Only when I run it from WIN+R

Comment: I just did a pip install of pyperclip from the Anaconda prompt and now is working. I still don't understand why using WIN+R would run Anaconda packages rather then python packages already installed previously but at the moment seems to solve the problem. Thanks very much @furas for the aswers.

Comment: usually when people install Anaconda they expect it will run as default python, directly after installing. They don't want to digg in settings and search solutions on internet. And this is why Anaconda set its Python as default one. People which install standard Python expect the same.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent couple of hours trying to solve exactly the same problem. What I found out is that, as couple of members have already pointed out, the main problem is the mismatch between the version of the python that runs in cmd and the versions of the python used in scripts/batch files.

The first line in the code, known as "shebang", in .py file indicates the version of the python that the script should use when it is executed. So, it must match the version run by default with cmd (or when executed with win+R). In my case, I also have a batch file (.bat) that calls specified version of the python, which should be the same version used with .py file.

The problem was that both of my files (.py and .bat) were calling python 3.8 while the cmd is running version 3.7. Initially, I used shebang **#! python3** in my *.py* file, and command **@py path/to/python/file.py %*** (and I also tried **@py.exe path/to/python/file.py %***) in my *.bat* file, and that did not work.

To solve the problem, I updated these two files to link to **python version 3.7** with following:

- changed shebang in *.py* file to **#! python**
- changed command in *.bat* file to **@python path/to/python/file.py %***

With these changes the system runs the program with win+R.

Answer (score 0):

whew, taking course on python and instructor had py.exe instead of python.exe in .bat call. despite trying all of the other installation methods others have mentioned, just changing this to python.exe did that trick.